# Batch Function Not Copying Properly

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy

```
REM Capture the date/time(right down to the second) and then assign it to a variable
set yy=%date:~-4%
set dd=%date:~-7,2%
set mm=%date:~-10,2%
set newdate=%dd%%mm%%yy%_%Time:~0,8%
set newdate=%newdate::=%
SET foldername="svetlana_backup_%newdate%"

SET drive=T: 

REM Source directories
SET documents=%drive%\Documents

REM Destination directories
SET destinationDocuments=%backupDir%\Documents

call:makedirandcopy %documents% %destinationDocuments%

:makedirandcopy
ECHO Making and Copying %~2 Directory
MKDIR %~2
XCOPY %~1 %~2 /E /F
```

I have the following batch file on my desktop, when I run the batch file, it **supposed to** make a directory on my destination drive and copy all the documents, however, it makes the directory, and the documents subdirectory, **but** on my desktop, where the batch file resides, and never copies the files in Documents. The file name is also incorrect, it just assigns the time to the directory instead of the date_time.

```
Passing T:\Documents "T:\Backup"\"svetlana_backup_23022016_ 91300"\Documents
Making and Copying T:\Backup"\"svetlana_backup_23022016_ 91300"\Documents Directory
Making and Copying  Directory
0 File(s) copied
```

If I were to do all of this without the label it works.

Comment: At a glance looks like there could be an issue with the quotes.Try with `SET "foldername=svetlana_backup_%newdate%"`

Comment: @npocmaka - Close, it created the folder on the drive, but came back with the same parse error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
call :makedirandcopy %documents% %destinationDocuments%
goto :EOF    

:makedirandcopy
ECHO Making and Copying %~2 Directory
MKDIR "%~2"
XCOPY "%~1" "%~2" /E /F
goto :EOF
```

From your run report, you have a line

```
Passing T:\Documents "T:\Backup"\"svetlana_backup_23022016_ 91300"\Documents
```

There is nothing in the code you've posted that will generate that line.

You then have

```
Making and Copying T:\Backup"\"svetlana_backup_23022016_ 91300"\Documents Directory
Making and Copying  Directory
```

The cause of this is that you are `call`ing `:makedirandcopy` (which displays the first line) and when the `call`ed routine ends (presumably it reaches end-of-file) control is returned to the statement following the `call` - which is the routine again, this time with no parameters, hence the second line.

Try

```
call :makedirandcopy "%documents:"=%" "%destinationDocuments:"=%"
goto :EOF
```

which will remove the excess quotes in each of the variables and quote the result.

Note that since there are spaces in the parameters being passed to `:makedirandcopy`, `xcopy` will require those parameters quoted.

Perhaps you'd also need

```
...
set newdate=%newdate::=%
set newdate=%newdate: =0%
...
```

to replace the suppressed-leading-zero in the time with a real, genuine `0`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Just out of curiosity, how did you learn about the `=%`? I've been reading and learning about batch files but never came across that.

Comment: See `set /?` from the prompt - it's in the documentation.